# DRF : How to enable/disable other fields' editing depending on a specific field's value?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model of blog contents like this:

```
class BlogContents:
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft Content'),
        ('published', 'Publish Content'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    content = models.TextField(null=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft', null=False)
```

I want to allow an user to do anything (i.e., list, create, retrieve, update, delete) with this model whenever the `status` field value of the instance is `draft`. However, when the `status` field value is changed to `published`, I want to disable the 'update' action of that instance.

How can I achieve this scenario in Django-rest-framework?

Answer (score 0):

In your view override the `update` method, where you check value of `status` at the very beginning.

The second way is to create permission class, that will check method and status. But, I think, it's a little bit overkill using permission class for such task

Answer (score 0):

To solve problems like determine whether a request should be granted or denied access for a particular object, permissions are a more appropriate approach

Create a [custom permission class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) and override the instance-level `has_object_permission` method

```
from rest_framework import permissions    


class IsDraftOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Disabling POST and PUT methods for non-draft objects (published)
        return (
            obj.status == 'draft' or
            request.method in ('GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'DELETE')
        )
```

Then, set the authentication policy to your view through `permission_classes` attribute